# How can I find $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{(\frac{n}{n^2+1}+\frac{n}{n^2+2}+ \cdots + \frac{n}{n^2+n})}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I am having troubles with this limit:

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{(\frac{n}{n^2+1}+\frac{n}{n^2+2}+ \cdots + \frac{n}{n^2+n})}$

The denominators make an arithmetic progression, I have tried to calculate it, but it didn't help me. Any ideas, how to solve it?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I have made some edits to your post. Please ensure that they are correct `:)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: $$\frac{n}{n^2+1}\cdot n>\frac{n}{n^2+1}+\cdots+\frac{n}{n^2+n}>\frac{n}{n^2+n}\cdot n$$

Comment: Clever :-), thanks a lot....

Answer (score 2):

For problems like these, one good try is always squeeze theorem.

Note that $\dfrac{n}{n^2+1}+\cdots +\dfrac{n}{n^2+n} \leq \dfrac{n^2}{n^2+1}$, and that

$\dfrac{n}{n^2+1}+\cdots +\dfrac{n}{n^2+n} \geq \dfrac{n^2}{n^2+n} \rightarrow 1$, and so the limit is $1$ by the sqeeze theorem.